# highland.js event handlers not firing as expected

Tags: node.js, highland.js

I am trying to use the request library which streams responses. Following code works as expected.

```
request.get('http://someurl.com')
  .on('response', function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode) // 200
});
```

However, when I try to do the same thing with highland.js the event handler is never fired.

```
var r = request.get('http://someurl.com');
var p =_('response', r);
  p.map(function(x){
  console.log(x.statusCode);
});
```

Is there something super trivial that I am missing here?

Comment: Are you causing a thunk at any stage in your chain? Unless you do something like toArray() or each() the stream will never be read from.

Comment: You are right. I also need to cause a thunk. However, the problem was also that I did have wrap it in a highland stream.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. Highland expects a Highland stream in order to listen for events. The following code works as expected.

```
_(request(opts))
  .on('response', function(response){
     console.log(response.statusCode)
  })
```

You can further use this highland stream to perform things like map, filter, etc.